# What linguistic feature would I draw upon to explain this?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, linguistics, rhetorical-devices

If i was writing an informative piece on a random topic and I wrote for instance "Ok, but how does CO2 get released? By burning fossil fuels." By asking a question to my intended audience and then answering it, I am not using a rhetorical question in my opinion which leads me to ask.. what would that language feature/strategy be?

(English Language teacher in need of help!)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Answering your own question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/13532/answering-your-own-question). Sven Yargs gives other ballpark answers. // Note that, to parallel "How does CO2 get released?", "By the burning of fossil fuels" is strictly required. "How do we get CO2 to be released" is matched by "By [our] burning fossil fuels".

Answer (score 1):

**Hypophora**:

> Hypophora is a figure of speech in which a writer raises a question, and then immediately provides an answer to that question.
>   (From https://literarydevices.net/hypophora/)

It Is used to generate curiosity in the listener/reader, rather like a medic running using water to induce urination.

See also **anthypophora** and **antipophora**, which Wikipedia lists as synonyms. All three are figures of *speech* in general- not only literary devices.

Comment: Ach-, it's a duplicate of Edwin Ashworth's pointer!